# Moving NearProtocol Node IP

Tags: blockchain, nearprotocol, near, nearcore

When moving a node (non validator) to a new IP:

A) is it ok to use the same chain data with a new node key?

B) would peers seeing the same node key on a new IP cause any issues with inbound connections to the node on a new IP?

c) how/when do peers update the IP under which they expect to find a known node key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) Yes, it is fine to use the same data with the same or new node key

B) Nope, everything should work smoothly unless there are two nodes at the same time using the same node key

C) Nodes don't keep track of IP addresses explicitly, as far as I know, they only care about TCP connections